# How to prolong screenshot snippets time (Mac)

Tags: macos, screen-capture

When you take screenshots you have small snippets at the bottom right corner. It is very useful to drag and drop. But it disappears too quickly. The default interval is 5 seconds.

**How can I tweak time of that snippets?**

[image]

Comment: I had to get in the habit of clicking them to open the edit panel. Then I can set that window aside until I’m ready to share it or post process it. It will be interesting if there’s some easy way to influence the interval “behind the scenes” - having the proxy image for drag and drop is super useful.

Comment: Here is solution how to change thumbnail showing time: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74140663/increase-the-duration-of-the-floating-thumbnail-screenshot-preview-on-macos/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74140663/increase-the-duration-of-the-floating-thumbnail-screenshot-preview-on-macos/74142493#74142493)

Answer (score 6):

This is not the answer to the question but an alternative to achieve desired result as I see it.

One can copy screenshot to clipboard and then paste it into application/file needed. For that to work just press ⌃ (Control) while taking screenshot. Then ⌘+V in desired file/application to paste screenshot from clipboard. In case of Preview it's sufficient to open new Preview window (⌘+N) and screenshot from clipboard is displayed automagically.

Comment: Me just wonders about downvote. OP stated what he wants to do: "It is very useful to drag and drop."  This means that objective is to move screenshot made somewhere but preview of file disappears too quickly.  So it should be viable option to take screenshot to clipboard and have full control over the time delay while deciding where to 'move' it when saving. This is keyboard oriented solution and not 'drag-and-drop' but it delivers the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at the plist for Screen Capture and there doesn't seem to be a time period to extend the time the thumbnail stays on screen. But you can disable/enable the thumbnail and/or change the default location the screenshot is saved to. For me, I have all my screenshots saved to Desktop so it's easily accessible for editing and have thumbnails disabled.

To change these two settings open the app `Screenshot` by searching in Spotlight. You will then get a cropped window and bar with options at the bottom of the cropped window. Click on `Options` and you'll see "Show floating thumbnail" and "Save to" options. You can enable/disable floating thumbnail and/or save all screenshots to another file location by default.

See image below for an example:

[image]

By the way, behind the cropped area (on the left), you will see the plist file for screen capture that I was looking at. As you can see there isn't a value to change the thumbnail length.

Hope this may help somewhat for you :)